# pd.date_range for 9am each day between two pd.Timestamp objects

Tags: python, pandas

What I have:

```
pd.Timestamp('2021-07-05 08:10:11')
pd.Timestamp('2021-07-07 12:13:14')
```

What I'm looking for:

```
[pd.Timestamp('2021-07-05 09:00:00'), 
 pd.Timestamp('2021-07-06 09:00:00'), 
 pd.Timestamp('2021-07-07 09:00:00')]
```

It feels like I should be able to do this with some combination of of `pd.date_range` and `pd.offsets`, but I can't find the right combination.

Given that 9am is the standard meteorological time point, I'm hoping someone has a nice solution for this already!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is way more fiddly and annoying than expected...

So much so that I've created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/cjw296/73af04f7a4dcbc39f2ec01384bf5aa90) with a small suite of unit test and a selection of possible solutions.

Currently, the only working solution is this one, which isn't as pretty or succinct as I feel pandas should be capable of:

```py
start = start.round('D') + pd.Timedelta(hours=9)
[x for x in pd.date_range(start, end, freq='1D')
 if start <= x <= end]
```

If you find cases where the above doesn't work, please
let me know so I can add a test for it, and propose a solution
if you're able!

Answer (score 2):

#### Method 1

We can use `datetime.replace` with `pd.date_range` and a frequency of `D`:

```
start = pd.Timestamp('2021-07-05 08:10:11').replace(hour=9, minute=0, second=0)
end = pd.Timestamp('2021-07-07 12:13:14').replace(hour=9, minute=0, second=0)

pd.date_range(start, end, freq='D')
```

```
DatetimeIndex(['2021-07-05 09:00:00', '2021-07-06 09:00:00',
               '2021-07-07 09:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

---

#### Method 2: Using [`pd.offsets.BusinessHour`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.BusinessHour.html)

We can pass an offset to `pd.date_range` and in this case we can use `BusinessHour` since it will by default use `09:00`.

```
start = pd.Timestamp('2021-07-05 08:10:11')
end = pd.Timestamp('2021-07-07 12:13:14')

dates = pd.date_range(start, end, freq=pd.offsets.BusinessHour()).to_series()
dates.groupby(dates.dt.date).min()
```

```
2021-07-05   2021-07-05 09:00:00
2021-07-06   2021-07-06 09:00:00
2021-07-07   2021-07-07 09:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

To set another start time, we can set the `start` argument in `pd.offsets.BusinessHour`

Comment: I agree, added another method with `pd.offsets.BusinessHour`.  Note it seemed a bit buggy making use of the `start` argument. I will open an issue for this on github.

Comment: Opened an [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/42399)

Comment: Not a misunderstanding imo. I would expect the same behaviour, since BusinessDays does skip weekends.

Comment: I'm afraid neither of these methods actually work correctly, I'm surprised how annoying this is! Here's a gist with a test suite... test_start_after_end_before is the one that's failing for both of the above methods:

https://gist.github.com/cjw296/73af04f7a4dcbc39f2ec01384bf5aa90